# Bootstrap button wraps when the page gets smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When my resolution gets smaller, one of my buttons wraps to the bottom of the screen. I'm not sure how to fix this:

[image: Smaller Screen]

Here is the code for the HTML and the CSS:

http://pastebin.com/PWXWUMdg

I'm sure there's some sort of wrapping issue with the buttons, I'm just unsure what the change.

Comment: You'r paste bin is fairly long. Try to drill down to the most relevant parts and include those bits of code directly in your question. You are more likely to get help that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem might be at row 110

padding-left: 290px"

Try to add @media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) { ... }
And select by a specifically added new class to this div and remove that padding or make it smaller.

Actually it's inline style, so it has higher priority, so you would need to remove it and add it with some {your-name}.css external style, or internal `<style></style>` on page.